# How to iterate using vector of vector of pair in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

i would like to ask how do you iterate over vector of vector of pair? supposed i have the following.

```
typedef pair<int,int> Pair;
vector<vector<Pair> > adjList;
```

and then i tried to iterate using the following code:

```
vector<vector<Pair> > :: iterator i;
vector<Pair> :: iterator it;
for(i = adjList[N].begin(); i != adjList[N].end(); ++i)
{
   for(it = adjList[N].begin(); it != adjList[N].end(); ++it)
   //and the rest of the code
```

however it returns an error

```
'no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector > >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >*, std::vector > > >}’ and ‘std::vector >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >}’)'.
```

anyone knows? thanks.

Comment: What does `N` represent in this code ??

Comment: Why do you expect `adjList[N].begin()` to have two different types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use range-based for-loops and structured bindings:

```
for(auto& inner : adjList) {
    for(auto& [first, second] : inner) {
        first = ...;
        second = ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Stuck with an older version at work, are you? I know the feeling. :-)

Comment: Yes, but hopefully not for long. `if constexpr` will change my life ...

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Indeed! ... and structured bindings are also very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is you are using the first elements, iterator for the outer list here:

```
for(i = adjList[N].begin(); i != adjList[N].end(); ++i)
```

where you clearly meant for `i` to be an iterator over the outer list. You probably meant to do this:

```
for(i = adjList.begin(); i != adjList.end(); ++i)
```

But for ease and readability, use a range based for loop:

```
for (const auto& row : adjList) {
    for (const auto& pair : row) {
       // print pair.second or whatever
```

Remove the 2 `const`s if you want to edit the pair.

Comment: does the array inside the for loops have to be a 2d array as well? for example, int visited[i]it].

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = adjList[N].begin(); i != adjList[N].end(); ++i)
```

This iterates over the nth inner vector not over the outer vector beside `i` type is not consistent with the type of `adjList[N].begin()` and what's that `N`.

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>


typedef std::pair<int,int> Pair;
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<Pair> > adjList;

    std::vector<std::vector<Pair> >::iterator i;
    std::vector<Pair>::iterator it;
    for (i = adjList.begin(); i != adjList.end(); ++i)//iterating over the outer vector
    {
        for (it = i -> begin(); it != i -> end(); ++it)//over the inner ones
        {
            it -> first = ...;//assign to the first of the pair
            it -> second = ...;//assign to the second of the pair
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i was trying to only traverse through the output(in my case i am implementing a graph). i have already added the edges and vertices, now i am trying to mark the visited edges. is there a need to assign the pair again?

Comment: @qwertyuiop no there is no need. I did that only to show you how to reach the elements of the pairs. you can use `std::cout << it -> first` to show the output instead of reassigning.

Comment: @qwertyuiop I used this way to show you where the errors are but if I were u I would use TedLyngmo 's one

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<vector<Pair> > :: iterator i;
vector<Pair> :: iterator it;
for(i = adjList.begin(); i != adjList.end(); ++i)
{
   for(it =(*i).begin(); it != (*i).end(); ++it){}
}
```

And  if your project uses C++11 or later, use `auto` to simplify `typedef`;

```
for(auto i = adjList.begin(); i != adjList.end(); i++){
   for(auto itr = (*i).begin(); itr != (*i).end(); itr++){
  }
}
```

Moreover, with for-range:

```
for(auto & i:adjList){
  for(auto &j: i){
    // xxxx
  }
}
```